# HTML/CSS - Issue justifying divs

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

I'm coding a template for an image gallery. On its content pages, it presents a list of all albums or images side by side, divided by lines when the content reaches its width. I'm trying to get the content to appear justified, i.e. have the images spread out evenly through the page.

For this, I'm using this code:

```
#content_list{
    width:100%;
    text-align:justify;
}
```

For the parent div, and the following one for the divs inside it:

```
.item{
    width:164px;
    height:214px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

In order to force the last line to justify regardless of the number of items, I'm using an empty div at the end with the following style:

```
.forceextra{
    width:100%;
    display:inline-block;
    height:1px;
}
```

Now, here's the problem I ran into: The template is being coded to work as per liquid design, ie. the amount of images per line and the space between them dynamically changes depending on the browser width, which has the added advantage of allowing the site to work as responsive without any extra work.

However, when there aren't enough images to fill up the last line (Which happens depending on the browser width), browsers make it so that one image appears to the left and another one to the right side of the last line, making it look bad. So I'm wondering, in order to fix this issue, is there a way to prevent this, that is, to make it so the images on the last line appear just as the ones before without having a set website width?

EDIT: Here's a fiddle showing the issue:

http://jsfiddle.net/jd4s3/

Comment: please post a jsfiddle of your code if possible... its easier to work on the problem than to try to read through your code and solve.

Comment: Sorry, I had to spend a couple of days away from my computer. Here's the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/jd4s3/

What I need is a way for the last line of items to appear with the same separation between them than the previous lines have. Do notice that, since it's meant to be a liquid design, the amount of items per line changes as the window size changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using [wookmark jquery plugin](http://www.wookmark.com/jquery-plugin) which is very suitable for your liquid design.

[Demo](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Dynamic-Grid-Layout-Plugin/example/)

Answer (score 1):

Once you get more than four columns you ran into problems with this approach, i don't think this is the best way to do it, but up to some extent you are ok, after that you should use media queries, modifying the `text-aling`, to use `left` instead of `justify`, adding margin right to the items, and removing the same margin from the last items in your cols using `:nth` element. If it were me, based on what you did, i will use `text-align: left` from the start, with margins and then for each case i'll change the nth element margin removal, like this:

```
#content_list{
    width:100%;
    text-align:left;
}

.item{
    width:164px;
    height:214px;
    margin-right:5px;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:#cc3355;
}

.forceextra{
    width:100%; display:inline-block; height:1px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 543px){
    /*3 columns*/
    #content_list div:nth-child(3n){
        margin-right:0;
    } 
}

@media screen and (min-width: 693px){
    /*4 columns*/
    #content_list div:nth-child(4n){
        margin-right:0;
    } 
}
```

[**jsfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jd4s3/1/)

For every set of columns (depending on the screen width) you'll have to add a single media query for that, changing the nth-child argument.

**Note:** Be aware that i'm just pointing you out in the right direction, the exact amount of pixels needed for every query must be checkeb by you, so my example is not perfect.

Comment: Though a somewhat valid method, this creates differing margins between images (As seen in your demo) that would cause the design team to send this whole thing back to me as soon as they saw it. Hardcoding the margins is in itself an issue because we want the items to take up all the available space. Still, this was the solution I had first thought of, so it might help someone with different needs.

Comment: You will need to set the media queries correctly, you will only need like 6 depending on your needs, if you set them correctly there is no need to get in trouble with the design team, you only have to hardcode depending on how many columns are setted depending on the screen width. Fluid layouts has a limit, and after that you have to use responsive layout with media queries. The other option is to use jQuery, but since you didn't tag it, i gave you a css solution.

Comment: I'm aware. However, since we want for the items to fill the full width of the site at all times (except for the last content line), hardcoding margins isn't an option for us. I ended up using the Jquery  answer another user gave me. Sorry I didn't tag as Jquery, I mostly wanted to know if there was a not javascript way to attain this, although I wasn't limited by it.